# How to set workflows in a Sitecore environment with SXA and Helix?

Tags: helix, workflow, habitat

We are working on a Sitecore 8.2 project which is based on Helix and SXA.

Now we want to implement Sitecore workflows. As of definition of Helix, you set them on page/data templates in the project layer.

Looking at the Habitat project, you see that all datasources are in the feature layer, which would make it impossible to set workflows on.

How does this fit together? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

My two cents

If to go strictly after the Helix documentation it seems like both the workflows and the datasources should belong to the project layer:

https://helix.sitecore.net/principles/templates/template-types.html

and

https://helix.sitecore.net/principles/security/workflows.html

So it would seem that there is a discrepancy between the Helix Documentation and the Habitat implementation on this point. That being said helix is a set of principles and guidelines. This is not necessarily the same as a specific solution should adhere to them 100%. Rather it pushes architects and developers to consider them, knowing when and why they are choosing to sidestep them in a specific situation.

Habitat is an example implementation, which of course as any other implementation can have made compromises to the guidelines for one reason or another.

Comment: And then there is the discussion of whether stuff like SXA (or even habitat if you are applying that as base) in reality becomes part of Foundation in your solution - but that is I think for another forum than this.

Comment: And there is a MUCH larger discussion about when you are using datasourced components on your page (like an RTE or CTA). Those datasources are not included in the pages workflow. If you have 5 datasoures on a page, you have to workflow all those separately. I have not found a viable way to handle this yet.

Comment: Very true and that gets even more complicated when the datasources are not only used for that particular page...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your view on this issue. My thoughts were heading in a similar direction, but I find it strange, that not even THE sample solution for Helix is following it by 100%. As you stated it is more or less meant to be adjusted, but at this point, the guideline does not make sense to me, so it would have been great to have an example that 'proved' me wrong :)